# what is the difference between enabling interrupts and restoring interrupts?

Tags: operating-system, linux-kernel, kernel, interrupt

I have big confusion on this. Can any one explain me the difference between this??

When do we use Enable and when do we use restore. Both mean the same or are they different???

I know enable is used when disable is used . And restore is used when we save the interrupts.

But, when and where do we use them???

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where excatly did you come across these? I would like to know the context to give more details. AFAIK its like this

Restore interrupt: means restore interrupt flag to the state prior ie old state
    `void _restore_interrupts(unsigned int);`

Enable interrupt: It enables the interrupt flag and enables Interrupt service routines to run ie `STI` instruction under x86
    `unsigned int _enable_interrupts();`

Normally for a critical section `cli` instruction is used to disable interrupts so that no other ISR is run. When the critical section is over the `STI` instruction is used to enable interrupts

Comment: Restoring interrupts if often used with locks. When you lock, you disable interrupts (for some locks). But they may have already been disabled. So when you unlock, you don't enable them, but restore them (which would enable if they were enabled before).